# Problem adding two 4x4 matrices and printing the sum result in a new matrix in C

Tags: c, matrix

Could someone help me please?

I need to perform the sum of two matrices that the data will be sent by the user and print the result in a new matrix.

I managed to capture the data from the two arrays, but when I try to add the two, the code does not print the sum, where is the error?

Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sum(int *mat_A, int *mat_B, int *mat_C);

int main() {

    int mat_A[4][4];
    int mat_B[4][4];
    int mat_C[4][4];
    int i, j, value;

    printf("\nEnter integer values ​​for the elements of matrix A: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            printf("\nElement[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
            scanf_s("%d", &value);
            mat_A[i][j] = value;
        }
    }

    printf("\nEnter integer values ​​for the elements of matrix B: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            printf("\nElement[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
            scanf_s("%d", &value);
            mat_B[i][j] = value;
        }
    }

    calc_soma(*mat_A, *mat_B, *mat_C);

    printf("\nSum of matrices A with B: \n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            value = mat_C[i][j];
            printf("%d", value);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

void sum(int *mat_A, int *mat_B, int *mat_C) {

    int i, j;
    int value;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            value = *mat_A + *mat_B;
            *mat_C = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `int *mat_A` is a pointer to a 1-dimensional array, not a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: You're not updating `mat_A`, `mat_B`, and `mat_C` in the loop, so you keep reading and writing the first element of all the arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare the parameters to `sum()` as 2-dimensional arrays, not `int *`, which is a pointer to a 1-dimensional array. Then use `i` and `j` as array indexes.

You're also calling the function with the wrong name `calc_soma`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sum(int mat_A[4][4], int mat_B[4][4], int mat_C[4][4]);

int main() {

    int mat_A[4][4];
    int mat_B[4][4];
    int mat_C[4][4];
    int i, j, value;

    printf("\nEnter integer values for the elements of matrix A: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            printf("\nElement[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
            scanf_s("%d", &value);
            mat_A[i][j] = value;
        }
    }

    printf("\nEnter integer values for the elements of matrix B: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            printf("\nElement[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
            scanf_s("%d", &value);
            mat_B[i][j] = value;
        }
    }

    sum(mat_A, mat_B, mat_C);

    printf("\nSum of matrices A with B: \n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            value = mat_C[i][j];
            printf("%d", value);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

void sum(int mat_A[4][4], int mat_B[4][4], int mat_C[4][4]) {

    int i, j;
    int value;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            value = mat_A[i][j] + mat_B[i][j];
            mat_C[i][j] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: aaah yes thanks, so in the parameters of the sum function I must declare that the matrices are 4x4.

And is there any way that these parameters are pointers or would that be unfeasible for this type of matrix?